# Embedded Resources JSON to JObject

Tags: c#, json

In a .NET 4.6 C# Class Library I have an embbed JSON file. I try to convert this to a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject like this:

```
string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.test);
JObject t2 = JObject.Parse(json);
```

When I inspsect "json" it shows:

```
"{\r\n  \"a\": \"b\"\r\n}"
```

The parse gives the following error: ": 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0.'"

I could chop off the first and last ", but is there any native way to read this embedded JSON file? Also I don't understand why it puts the extra " in the beginning and end, it is not present in my json file.

Comment: `line 0, position 0.'"` means that it is the first character of the string which is the problem. Almost certainly you have a BOM as the first character. `if(json[0] == 0xfeff){json = json.Substring(1);)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.test)` returns the exact same value you posted, but when I tried with that json it's working:

```
string json = "{\r\n  \"a\": \"b\"\r\n}";

//take 1
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var value = obj.Property("a").Value; // Returns: b

//take 2
var obj2 = JObject.Parse(json);
var value2 = obj2.Property("a").Value; // Returns: b
```

Also, quotes are not added "for real", this is just way of displaying strings in Visual Studio (i.e. Visual Studio adds those quotes when displaying string values)

Comment: Somehow Encoding.UTF8.GetString adds these quotes. Sort of the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169680/unquote-string-in-c-sharp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Trim does not work for me, but if I pop this line of code before the parse it works fine: 
json = json.Substring(1, json.Length - 1);